# Pixel-to-RA/DEC mapping in digitized astrophotography

Tags: astrophotography

I have a 1443x998 picture of the stars (taken w/ a 35mm camera and 
then scanned) with the following stars at the following pixel locations:

```
Altair x=782, y=532 [19h50m46.9990s RA, +08 52'05.959'' DEC] 
Sualocin, x=311, y=146 [20h 39m 38.287s +15 54'43.49'' DEC] 
Denebokab, x=1023, y=815 [19h25m29.9005s +03 06' 53.191'' DEC]
```

What mathematical function converts pixel location to RA/DEC and vice 
versa? Notes:

- Bright stars are blobs in the picture; the coordinates above are 
  roughly the center of the blob, but may be off by +-2 pixels.
- I know I can rotate the celestial sphere so that the center of my 
  picture has polar coordinates 0,0. So the real question is "how to 
  find this rotation" (but see next point).
- If elevation/azimuth were linear in pictures, this would be 
  easy(er), but they're not: 
  [Measuring angular distance with photographs](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/measuring-angular-distance-with-photographs/)
- I can provide pixel locations of more stars if that helps. I 
  believe 3 should be sufficient, but I could be wrong.
- I tried to choose 3 stars that were "spread out" across the 
  picture (because I think that reduces error, not sure), but am not 
  sure I succeeded.
- I'm doing this for several pictures and would like a general method.
- Doing this will help me identify fainter stars/Messier-objects/etc 
  in the picture.
- I'm sure lots of astrophotographers want to do this, but haven't 
  found any existing software that does this.

EDIT: Thanks, whuber! The gnomonic projection is what I was missing. I'd 
already done this assuming a linear transformation:

```
(* convert RA/DEC to xyz coords on celestial psuedo-sphere of radius 1 *) 
radecxyz[ra_,dec_] = 
{Cos[ra/12*Pi]*Cos[dec/180*Pi],Sin[ra/12*Pi]*Cos[dec/180*Pi],Sin[dec/180*Pi]}; 

(* I no longer have any idea how this works *) 
astrosolve[x_,y_,z_,xwid_,ywid_] := Module[{a,m,ans,nullans}, 
m=Array[a,{2,3}]; 
temp=Solve[{ 
m.radecxyz[x[[1]],x[[2]]]=={x[[3]]-xwid/2,x[[4]]-ywid/2}, 
m.radecxyz[y[[1]],y[[2]]]=={y[[3]]-xwid/2,y[[4]]-ywid/2}, 
m.radecxyz[z[[1]],z[[2]]]=={z[[3]]-xwid/2,z[[4]]-ywid/2} 
}]; 
ans = m /. Flatten[temp]; 
nullans=Flatten[NullSpace[ans]]; 
If[nullans.radecxyz[x[[1]],x[[2]]]<0,nullans=-nullans]; 
Return[{ans,nullans}]; 
];
```

where x, y, and z were each 4-element lists consisting of a stars RA, 
declination, x-coordinate on picture, and y-coordinate on 
picture. xwid and ywid are the width and height of the picture. In 
this case:

```
astrosolve[ 
 {19.8463886110, 8.8683219443, 782, 532}, 
 {20.6606352777, 15.9120805555, 311, 146}, 
 {19.4249723610, 3.1147752777, 1023, 815}, 
 1443, 998] 

{ 
 {{-2250.51, -1182.52, 385.689},  {-166.12, -543.746, -2376.73}},  
 {0.480698, -0.861509, 0.163497} 
}
```

Now, referring to "{-2250.51, -1182.52, 385.689}" as $frow, "{-166.12, 
-543.746, -2376.73}" as $srow, and "{0.480698, -0.861509, 0.163497}" 
as $null, this PHP subroutine translates RA/DEC to xy coordinates:

```
# radecxy(ra,dec): converts ra/dec to x,y using a quasi-linear transformation 

function radecxy($ra,$dec) { 
    global $null,$frow,$srow,$xwid,$ywid; 
    list($x,$y,$z)=array(cos($dec)*cos($ra),cos($dec)*sin($ra),sin($dec)); 

    $dotprod=$null[0]*$x+$null[1]*$y+$null[2]*$z; 
    if ($dotprod<0) {return(array(-1,-1));}

 list($fx,$fy)  = array($frow[0]*$x+$frow[1]*$y+$frow[2]*$z,$srow[0]*$x+$srow[1]*$y+$srow[2]*$z); 
    $fx+=$xwid/2; 
    $fy+=$ywid/2; 
    if ($fx<0 || $fy<0 || $fx>$xwid || $fy>$ywid) { 
        return(array(-1,-1)); 
    } else { 
        return(array($fx,$fy)); 
    } 
}
```

Sadly, I no longer have any idea why this works, but using it + adding 
known star positions yields tolerable results (use "view image" to see it full size):

[image]

However, as you can see, the results aren't perfect, convincing me 
that a linear transformation wasn't the right answer. I think gnomonic 
might be the grail I was seeking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will outline a rigorous approach and indicate what software can help with it.  Most of this will be tangential to the interests of the photography site, but because there are some useful insights that *apply to any circumstance in which locations will be estimated from measurements on an image,* this site seems a reasonable place for such an analysis.

Taking an image (with a lens that has been corrected for distortion) projects the celestial sphere through the focal point of the lens onto the plane of the sensor.  This is *an oblique aspect of a [gnomonic projection](http://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/IRASdocs/surveys/coordproj.html).*

Mathematically, the conversion from (RA, DEC) proceeds through a series of steps:

1. Convert (RA, DEC) to spherical coordinates.  RA has to be converted from hours-minutes-seconds into degrees (or radians) and DEC has to be converted from degrees-minutes seconds into degrees (or radians), remembering that it is elevation above the plane, not angle from the north pole (which is the usual spherical coordinate convention).  Both conversions are simple arithmetic.
2. Compute (x,y,z) coordinates for the spherical coordinates of the stars.  This is a standard [coordinate conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) (involving simple trigonometry).
3. Rotate the celestial sphere to align its poles with the lens axis.  This is a linear transformation.
4. Rotate the celestial sphere around its poles to conform to the camera's orientation (another linear transformation).
5. Placing the imaging plane at a constant height *z* above the focal point, draw light rays from the stars at (x,y,z) through the focal point until they intercept the plane.  (This is the gnomonic projection and, by its nature, it is *projective* and not linear.)

[image]

[In the figure, which is intended to be a planar cross-section through the axis of the lens,

- A is the focal point.
- Semicircle BCD is the visible part of the celestial sphere.
- AC points along the axis of the lens.
- E, F, and G are star locations.
- EE, FF, and GG are their corresponding locations on the (invisible) celestial sphere.
- E', F', and G' are their images on the sensor KL (so that EE', FF', and GG' are paths of light rays from the stars to the sensor).
- AD is the horizon from which declination is measured.
- Alpha is the declination of star E (or, equivalently, an angular coordinate of EE).  Stars F and G have similar declinations (not shown).

Our task is to find the mathematical relation between the angular coordinates for E, F, and G--which are assumed known to high accuracy--such as alpha, and coordinates of their images E', F', and G', measured in pixels along the sensor.  Once found, this relation can be inverted as described below to estimate angular coordinates of celestial objects from positions of their images on the sensor.  Not shown, for simplicity, is the magnification of the lens.  With a distortion-free lens this will have the effect of uniformly rescaling the coordinates of E', F', and G' relative to the center of the sensor.]

This procedure describes how the light gets from a star onto the sensor for a perfect simple lens.  It involves these (unknown) parameters, which will need to be determined:

- Three angles in (3) and (4) describing the lens and camera orientation.
- A scale factor in (5) describing the combined effects of the sensor's size, distance from the focal point, and magnification of the lens.

Due to the projection (5), this is a complex, nonlinear transformation in general, but it has a definite mathematical description.  If we let x = (RA, DEC) designate a star's position, let *theta* represent the four parameters for the imaging process, and let y = (column, row) represent the pixel coordinates, then we can abstractly but more simply write

y = f(x, theta).

Next--and this is highly important--we need to account for errors.  The imaged stars are not in precise locations.  Thus we have to include an error term in our formula and it's conventional (since about 1800) to model this error probabilistically.  The new formula is

y = f(x, theta) + e

When the lens is distortion free, the expected value of *e* is 0 and its standard deviation (*sigma*) measures the typical size of error.  It's reasonable to assume the e's are approximately normally distributed, with approximately equal standard deviations (which is not true, but for an initial analysis it's a reasonable assumption) and we can hope these errors are statistically independent of each other (which again is not true but it's a good starting assumption).  This justifies a **least squares solution** using **[maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood)**.  Up to a universal constant, whose value we don't need to know, the log probability of any particular observation (x,y) equals

-|f(x, theta) - y|^2 / (2 sigma^2) - 2 log(sigma).

(The absolute value bars denote Euclidean distance in the imaging plane, computed as usual with the Pythagorean Theorem.)

By virtue of the assumed independence of errors, the log probability of the set of data for an image is the sum of these values.  This is the "log likelihood."  The maximum likelihood (ML) estimates of the parameters *theta* and *sigma* (five numbers in all) are those values that maximize the log likelihood.

We can, and should, go further.  The theory of ML also shows how to obtain confidence intervals for the estimates.  Intuitively, the errors in our observations create a little uncertainty in the joint values of the angles, the scale factor, and the standard deviation.  We need these values to estimate RA and DEC for any pixels in our image.  By using uncertain values, which is unavoidable, we will get uncertain results.  Furthermore, if we identify a pixel in our image by looking at a diffuse blob of light (scattered over approximately pi*sigma^2 pixels altogether), there will be *additional* uncertainty in the pixel coordinates.  Collectively these two forms of uncertainty combine.  This implies *the net uncertainty in estimating the RA and DEC of any blob of light on the image is larger than you would guess.*

Finally, when you're taking a measurement off the image and using that to estimate the true coordinates of a star or celestial object, you are doing [inverse regression](http://alexandria.tue.nl/extra1/afstversl/wsk-i/thonnard2006.pdf), which is a form of instrument calibration.  Inverse regression is a procedure to account for the uncertainties I just described.  Its output of course includes the estimated star coordinates for any blob of pixels on the image.  It also includes *a ring of coordinates around that estimate that are also consistent with the location of that blob.*  (This is a joint "inverse prediction interval" or a set of "fiducial limits" for the blob's RA and DEC.)  In practice, if you consult a catalog of celestial objects, you can use this ring to search for all known objects that are consistent with the information in your image.  Clearly this can be more valuable than a simplistic procedure that estimates--sometimes incorrectly--only one single set of coordinates.

**In summary,** what is needed here is software to

- Perform the nonlinear optimizing required by ML.
- Estimate standard errors in the estimates.
- Perform inverse regression.

Expertise with appropriate software, such [Stata](http://www.stata.com/)'s ML command or [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), is essential if you're coding this yourself.

Regardless of your expertise, **here are some conclusions you can use** in your imaging strategies:

- The accuracy of the image for getting a fix on any object can never be greater than the inherent imprecision in the imaging (as measured by *sigma*, the typical size of a point of light on the image).
- You can get close to this level of accuracy by identifying *many* known stars, not just three.  This reduces the uncertainty in the sky-to-image transformation almost to zero if you have enough known stars located in the image.
- It is correct that you want the reference stars to be spread across the image.  It is also *crucial* that they not be lined up (which, unfortunately, is the case with the three locations given in the question).  If you can afford to locate only three stars, get them in a nice triangle.  When the stars do line up, the statistical analysis indicates there is a *huge* uncertainty about locations in directions perpendicular to the line.  In this particular example the estimated error (*sigma*) is hundreds of pixels wide.  Having one more star to make a good triangle ought to reduce this error to one or two pixels.

Some parting thoughts:

- It is possible to detect and even correct lens aberrations by carrying out a more extensive statistical analysis.  The idea is to plot deviations between expected and actual locations of the stars on the image.  This is akin to "warping" or "[georeferencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georeference)" map data.  As a quick and dirty solution, you can press **GIS or image processing software** (such as [ENVI](http://www.ittvis.com/ProductServices/ENVI.aspx)) into service to georeference (or astroreference) any image.  Such software usually does not carry out ML estimates of projective transformations, but it can do high-order polynomial approximations.  An order-2 or order-3 polynomial transformation might do a good enough job, depending on your application.
- It is possible to improve accuracy by combining multiple images of the same objects.

Comment: I would like to point out, in response to a now-deleted comment that flashed on the screen for a second or so(!), that if you have accurate information about the lens orientation then you effectively know two or even three of the parameters (the angles).  This makes it easier to find the ML solution for the remaining parameter(s) (because there are fewer of them) and reduces some uncertainty, but it does not change the nature of the problem.  In the best case you also know the camera's orientation.  Finding the scale factor *is* a linear problem--you could even use a spreadsheet to solve it!

Comment: @whuber: Ok, before I respond, met me be clear what I'm responding to. Your statistical analysis is rock solid, and I'm only talking here about the optical issues. I'm ignoring statistical uncertainty and any imperfection in the imaging system. In practice when I've done image registration work, I indeed use a maximum likelihood approach, but I find that to be a bit beyond the scope of the question here. So what remains in your answer is the bit about transforming (RA, Dec) to (x,y). The flaw here seems to be in the way you think about the object and image planes when the object is at infinity

Comment: @whuber: In general, the gnomic projection you describe is indeed projective, but in the case of imaging at infinity, there can be no tilt of the object "plane." If you must think of it as an actual plane, then you must consider it to be normal to the optical axis. I also find it a bit odd that you speak of "Compute[ing] (x,y,z) coordinates for the spherical coordinates of the stars". This is unnecessary. It sounds like you have a strong background in numerical analysis, but little in optical engineering?

Comment: @whuber:  I design lenses and image processing algorithms professionally, so I may be using vocabulary which has a very specific meaning to optical engineers, and we may be having communication issues.

Comment: @Colin K To head off a possible extended discussion that is likely to be of little interest to most readers, let me point out there's no need to consider any objects "at infinity".  All real objects, including celestial ones, are at finite distances.  I invite you to criticize my analysis for finite objects, because I do not want to leave anyone deceived about the truth (least of all myself), but I won't respond to appeals about "objects at infinity" unless you're prepared to back them up rigorously with appropriate analysis using projective geometry.

Comment: @Colin K Ah, yes, communication between related but different fields can be fraught with unnecessary arguments.  (Full disclosure: my PhD is in differential geometry, not optics.  I'm thrilled you're participating here and look forward to reading all your future responses to any question)  But I hope that if we agree on what the problem is then we will also agree on what constitutes a correct solution.  Also, to keep on track, let's continue to bear in mind that the relevant ideas to bring out are those that address @barrycarter's original question.

Comment: @whuber: With a Ph.D in diff. geo., you unquestionably have the skills to understand what I'm trying to say. This is certainly a communication problem. So, let me take a different tack that may work better. First one quick point: "infinity" is a common term in optics meaning that all the rays through the pupil can be approximated as parallel to each other. All physical distances are finite, but while you need to re-focus when looking from an object 5 feet away to  one 10 feet away, this is not the case between one 5 lightyears an 10 lightyears -- both objects are "at infinity".

Comment: @whuber: Now, let me ask you some questions that may help our understanding. 1. My understanding of the coordinate transforms is mostly self taught for the purpose of image processing, so I'm sure there are some holes. Is it correct to say that an affine transform is a projective transform with equal scaling in both dimensions? 2. Can you describe a case where, with all objects at infinity, there would be unequal scale in the image relative to the angular position of the object? An example may be a field of stars which are arranged in a grid on the celestial sphere, but at varying distances.

Comment: @Colin K-- an affine transform is composed of rotation, translation, shear, and scaling transforms.  As such, it is possible that you're thinking of affine transforms differently than the general definition (which is better explained on wikipedia).  There would be no particular reason why the scaling and rotational components in an affine transform would be linked, although domain-specific knowledge may limit the actual transform used (as may be the case here).

Comment: @Colin K First, to echo @mmr: An affine transformation is a linear transformation followed by a translation.  One possible confusion here is that projective transformations can be written with matrices by means of projective coordinates (involving one more dimension), but even so there are projective transformations that are not affine.  Second, I have assumed isotropy (equal scales in all directions), although anisotropy can be handled by introducing one more parameter.  Third, light rays from stars at two different points in the sky converging towards a common point will *not* be parallel.

Comment: @whuber: Oh! I just realized you made an edit. Lemme take a look before I reply.

Comment: @whuber: From an optical perspective, Colin is indeed correct that, beyond a certain point, light rays from an object that reach the lens can be *considered* parallel for all incident rays. This is the case a lot of the time in landscape photography, as mountains and whatnot are often well beyond the "infinity focus" point. From a purely physical standpoint, I agree, rays from something even as far as a star are not perfectly parallel, but the angle of such rays will diverge so little that it is inconsequential. Given that...could an affine transform work?

Comment: @jrista I don't think that was the issue here, just a momentary diversion. I believe we are all on the same page regarding an object at infinity.

Comment: @jrista Given that two distinct stars have an angular separation, it is a given that their light rays will not be parallel.  Take a look at the coordinates in the question: they are fairly widely separated.  Sure, an affine transformation can approximate the correct projective one--that's the whole principle behind calculus, after all!--but with this kind of separation there will be small but perhaps unacceptable error.  Throwing in a second or third order polynomial correction can do a good job with similar georeferencing problems, so it ought to work here, too.

Comment: @whuber: So I looked at the figure you added, and the accompanying description. It seems to agree exactly with what I said. (Nice diagram by the way. Just keep in mind that if you model a lens as a "focal point" like that in too many situations, you're going to irritate a lot of optical engineers!) Based on that diagram, the pixel coordinate should scale like tan(alpha) should it not? All that remains is the scale factor to convert units of pixels to units with dimension of direction tangent, and rotation and translation to deal with the orientation of the camera.

Comment: @jrista (Continued) I should point out, too, that even with an affine approximation we still have a *nonlinear* relationship between the angular star coordinates and the rectilinear coordinates on the sensor.  I think you're right to suspect it's close to linear, but for (some) astrophotographic purposes it seems fair to assume one wants to wring all the accuracy out of the image that it can reasonably support.  I don't want to make a big deal out of this, but it is an interesting question whose analysis might help us to understand all photographic images a little better.

Comment: @whuber: rays from adjacent stars will of course not be parallel, but all the rays from ONE star will be! (in other words starlight is coherent). Thats the whole meaning of an object being at infinity. Also, I wonder, is this whole issue about the issue of approximating theta==tan(theta) ? because for any field of view you'll get in a telescope that is quite appropriate and common.

Comment: @Colin K That's exactly right (well, it's the cotangent, but so what...).  Yes, I get that bit about irritating optical engineers: their (and our) favorite part of the picture, the lens, got entirely left out!  I feel bad about that--there's a bit of hand-waving going on--but the point was to obtain a diagram that would help us see the nature of the coordinate transformations in question, not to analyze a lens.  I'm glad it is consistent with what you have been asserting.

Comment: @Colin K Part of it is the tan(theta) approximation but the main part of it is that theta itself is a (highly) nonlinear function of differences in RA and DEC.  This is where the 2D cross-section diagram might seem deceptively simple.  In effect theta has to be computed using spherical trigonometry and that computation is decidedly not an affine transformation of the celestial coordinates of the stars!

Comment: @whuber: Yeah thats a fine diagram for this purpose. Good looking too, what did you draw it with? The irritating part is that for most situations that "focal point" description will be very very wrong, and the name you give it uses terms that already have plenty of meaning in optics! Also it has no pupil, so it doesn't illuminate our little digression about an object at infinity, but thats really besides the point anyway.

Comment: @whuber: unless I am mistaken, apart from an additive offset, RA and Dec have exactly the same units as theta, do they not? They are angular coordinates describing a point on the celestial sphere. i.e. they are simply a specific set of spherical coordinates. Right?

Comment: @Colin K I think that the issue of (point) "object at infinity" for you may be tantamount to my (implicit) assumption that a star's image *ought* to be an infinitesimal point on the sensor (barring other physical effects like diffraction, lack of perfect focus, etc.)  Am I getting warm?

Comment: @Colin K (1) RA is longitude and DEC is latitude.  So sure they're angles but theta can be thought of as the (standardized) length of the geodesic joining two points on the sphere.  A crude approximation (for images covering only a few degrees of the sky) is to use (RA*cos(DEC), DEC) for coordinates and assume the image coordinates are an affine transformation of *those*.  (2) The software is "Geogebra" (freeware).  It's fun to use because you can move the parts of the figure (like the stars) and the rest of it moves right along, too!  http://www.geogebra.org/cms/

Comment: @whuber: That sounds like the issue then. Small angle approximations are common in optics. Especially if you're talking about astronomical observations, where the field of view is almost always very tiny.

Comment: @whuber, @Colin K: Thanks a lot for the discussion! :) I am not nearly as well versed in mathematics as the two of you, and I appreciate the discussion and clarifications. I am not entirely certain I fully understand everything, but I have the general gist, and understand whuber's assertations about there being a non-linear relationship between stars and the "focal point" of the lens. I guess the relationship becomes more non-linear the wider the field of view, so treating the problem as such makes sense.

Comment: As a side note...if you guys wish to discuss this in a more real-time fashion, don't forget that we have a chat system. You can click on the 'Photographic Memories' chat link to the right, click the 'All rooms' button, and create a chat room for any type of discussion. The beauty of our chat system is it logs everything permanently, so others, such as myself who are interested in the discussion, can review the log if we miss the real-time chat, and learn! :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this with the same degree of precision that professional astronomers do it would indeed be difficult. It would require you to have extremely precise characterization of the distortions produced by your lens, and the imperfections in your camera's sensor. However, you probably don't need that degree of accuracy. It should be sufficient for you to assume that your lens does not introduce large amounts of distortion (which is a good assumption for a quality lens) and that your cameras sensor is pretty close to a perfectly regular grid (which is a very good assumption for even a cheap camera).

All that remains is to work out the coordinate transformation that describes the orientation of the camera i.e. the direction it was pointed and the degree to which it was rotated.

What you are looking for then,  is called an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), or an affine map. Which is just a fancy name for a matrix by which you would multiply your pixel coordinates to obtain your astronomical coordinates. In the case of an affine map, this transformation can include any degree of rotation, scale, shear, and translation.

The meaning of the rotation component is pretty obvious. The scale factor simply describes how much of the sky is covered by each pixel in terms of RA/Dec. Shear is a transformation that would make the image of a rectangle become a parallelogram, but there shouldn't be any of this effect in an image of objects at infinity (like stars). Lastly, the translation component simple adds an offset to account for the fact that the (x = 0, y = 0) pixel in your image probably does not correspond to (RA = 0, Dec = 0).

Because you have 3 reference stars in your image, you have enough information to calculate the relationship between your pixel coordinates and the RA/Dec you are looking for. This would be done by linear least squares fit (not non-linear least squares as mentioned above) to determine the values of the matrix components that best match your pixel coordinates to the known RA/Dec of the reference stars. Once the matrix is established you can then apply it to the pixel coordinates of other stars to get their RA/Dec.

While I could do this relatively easily, I'm unfortunately unsure how to help you do it. It would involve some mathematical skill that is a bit beyond the scope of photo.SE. I'm an optical engineer, but I'm not much of a photographer; the software I would use for this is designed for engineers to do heavy-duty numerical computation, and isn't really a photographic tool at all. There may be ways to do this using software packages geared towards photographers, but I don't know about them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the transformation is not usually affine: it is projective.

Comment: I guess I am thinking about the problem more like whuber is, as a projection. I am curious to know if you could actually transform the OP's pixel coordinates into RA/DEC with an affine transform.

Comment: @whuber: In general yes, but not for objects at infinity. In fact, in this case the transformation is even more restrictive: it is a non-reflective similarity transform. This is a subset of the an affine transform for which the scale is equal in both directions and there is no shear. (non-reflective similarity is a special case of affine which is a special case of projective)

Comment: I beg to differ.  See the analysis in my recently posted response.